# why vue-slick-carousel isn't woarking?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider, carousel, slick.js

I've installed as a dependency vue-slick-carousel and vue3-slick-carousel, but neither of it works. I've done the setting as required, but the content is empty. Am I doing anything wrong ? The console gives an error -  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prevArrow'). I see it is related to slick-slider inner code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-router-starter-sj9hlz?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMain.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FNotMain.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHeader.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFooter.vue,src%2Fviews%2FShops.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <VueSlickCarousel v-bind="settings">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </VueSlickCarousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel'
import 'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css'
// optional style for arrows & dots
import 'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel-theme.css'

export default {
  components: { VueSlickCarousel },
  data() {
    return {
      settings: {
        arrows: true,
        dots: true,
      },
</script>
```

I'm expecting to see the vue slick slider on the page.

Comment: "neither of it works" - what's the problem? what errors are in the browser console? what debugging have you tried?

Comment: Having an error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prevArrow'). I see it is related to slick-slider inner code

Comment: it's been an open issue on [vue-slick-carousel](https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/issues/214) for almost 2 years - a repo that hasn't updated for almost THREE years - solution: don't use unmaintained libraries that have been abandoned by their authors